# How to configure Nginx Proxy Pass For Kibana Dashboard

Tags: nginx, kibana, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are working on integrating kibana dashboard into our front-end applications. instead of directly using kibana dashboard URL, we want to route via nginx. Eg. Kibana URL: `https://demo.elastic.co/app/dashboards#/view/kubernetes-b945b7b0-bcb1-11ec-b64f-7dd6e8e82013` We want to access this from below URL `https://example.com/kibana/<id>` We tried with below nginx configuration but it's not working.

```
location /kibana/ {
    rewrite ^/kibana/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://demo.elastic.co/app/dashboards#/view/kubernetes-b945b7b0-bcb1-11ec-b64f-7dd6e8e82013/;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing rewrite directive and adding `proxy_pass_header Host demo.elastic.co;`

Comment: I tried this, it's not working :(

Comment: if you want to use proxying https trafic you need add proxy_ssl_name, proxy_ssl_verify directives. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_name